# Notifier about visible ISS passes and/or Iridium flares for Ubuntu PC

Tags: linux, ubuntu, notification, astronomy

I am trying to find application that would be capable of notifying me about 
[visible ISS pases](http://spotthestation.nasa.gov/) for specified location and/or [visible Iridium flares](http://heavens-above.com/IridiumFlares.aspx) for specified location.

This software must be capable of running on Ubuntu.

I strongly prefer active open-source projects.

I know that there are multiple mobile apps but I want something that may run on Linux PC.